# Retrieving a bunch of videos from the remote xml file

Tags: android, video, saxparser, galleryview

I am having a button.`OnClick` of it I want to display a gallery consisting of videos and I want to play them when I click the gallery items consisting of these videos.

I am having a rough idea that the following code will do the trick and its better when we want to play a single video:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(""+taglist.getVideo().get(2))));
```

But what is the case in my scenario where I am having the xml file which consists of the `video` tags and values as below:

```
<video>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnF5_3puVUM</video>
<video>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1jB50Dszio</video>
<video>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mr2b72uLrzI</video>
<video>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcRO0pix_gI</video>
<video>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l79zUEfSqCo</video>
```

I am parsing my xml file using SAX Parser and would like to know how to display these in a Gallery view?